# how to click a table row and display additional info in table

Tags: php, html, jquery, pdo

I have a table that displays some info about each of our parts in the DB. My new task is to create a secondary "table" underneath each row that will display additional info.

They want to click on a row and then underneath that row the additional info will display. The additional info should not be visible until its "parent" row has been clicked.

My current code will only display the first row in the "child" row. some parts have a few different costs and dates associated with them. so if, for example, a part has 3 different costs. there should be 3 "child" rows underneath with those costs and the date for each. Right now it is only printing the first cost/date.

This is a dynamic table. The user enters a date range and all the parts that were purchased within that date range are displayed in the first table. is there anyway to get this to work with my code or do I need to go about this differently?

**HTML/PHP**

```
echo"
<table id='main'>
<tr>//header row
    <th>Part</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Location</th>
    <th>Lowest Cost Date</th>
    <th>Lowest Cost</th>
    <th>Highest Cost Date</th>
    <th>Highest Cost</th>
    <th>Difference</th>
</tr>";
while ($data = $sql->fetch((PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))){
echo"//main table
<tr class='clicked'>
    <td>";echo $data['part'];echo "</td>
    <td>";echo $data['description'];echo "</td>
    <td>";echo "HS";echo "</td>
    <td>";echo $data['min_cost_date'];echo "</td>
    <td>";echo $data['min_cost'];echo "</td>
    <td>";echo $data['max_cost_date'];echo "</td>
    <td>";echo $data['max_cost'];echo "</td>
    <td>";echo ($data['max_cost']-$data['min_cost']);echo "</td>
</tr>";
$sub_sql = $conn->query("select cost,qty_received from v_po_history where part = '".$data['part']."' and location = 'HS' and date_received >= '".$fd."' and date_received <= '".$sd."'");
while ($sub_data = $sub_sql->fetch((PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))){//also tried foreach here with fetchall
echo"
<tr class='sub_row'>
    <td>";echo $sub_data['cost'];echo "</td>
    <td>";echo $sub_data['date_received'];echo "</td>
    //verified data by doing a print_r($sub_row)
</tr>";
  };
};
echo "</table";
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.clicked').click(function() {
        $(this).next('.sub_row').slideToggle('slow');
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.sub_row {visibility:collapse;}
```

Comment: `$(this).next('.sub_row')`  - `.next()` looks at the very next *sibling* (only).  Your `sub_row` class is in a div in that sibling (edit and *must* be in a `<td>`, which it currently isn't), so should be `$(this).next().find(".sub_row")`

Comment: "*My current code doesn't hide the row on load*" - looks like it should, but note that the `<div class='sub_row'` must be in a `td` not directly in a `tr` - so the browser is probably rendering it outside the table.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your problem, but you can clean this up a little by wrapping your variables in curly braces instead of echoing like that. For example **<td>{$data['part']}</td>**

Comment: @freedomn-m thank you for your assistance. I couldn't get the row to hide using the div or using display:block. I had to apply Visibility:collapse; to the <tr> (removed the div) for the row to be "hidden". Now when I click on the parent row it does display data. However, I can't get it to display more than 1 sub_row even if there are more rows in the array. I print_r the $sub_data array and I can see more than 1 row. but using Fetch and fetchall I can't seem to get them to display. I will edit my code above. appreciate your help

Comment: The children of a table should not be other markup "echo"//main table" will be rendered as HTML and break the table structure or be rendered outside of the table

Comment: `next()` gets the next and only the next sibling, you'll need something like `.nextUntil(":not(.sub_row)")` (not sure that would work) - there's solutions on SO for this.

Comment: @freedomn-m .nextUntil('.clicked') worked perfectly for my situation. thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### working HTML/PHP code

```
echo 
"<table id='main'>
<tr>
    <th>Part</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Location</th>
    <th>Lowest Cost Date</th>
    <th>Lowest Cost</th>
    <th>Highest Cost Date</th>
    <th>Highest Cost</th>
    <th>Difference</th>
</tr>";
while ($data = $sql->fetch((PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))){
echo //main row
"<tr class='clicked'>
    <td>";echo $data['part'];echo "</td>
    <td>";echo $data['description'];echo "</td>
    <td>";echo "HS";echo "</td>
    <td>";echo $data['min_cost_date'];echo "</td>
    <td>";echo $data['min_cost'];echo "</td>
    <td>";echo $data['max_cost_date'];echo "</td>
    <td>";echo $data['max_cost'];echo "</td>
    <td>";echo ($data['max_cost']-$data['min_cost']);echo "</td>
</tr>";
$sub_sql = $conn->query("select cost,date_received from v_po_history where part = '".$data['part']."' and location = 'HS' and date_received >= '".$fd."' and date_received <= '".$sd."'");
$sub_data = $sub_sql->fetchall((PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
foreach ($sub_data as $row){
echo //sub row (cost,date received)
"<tr class='sub_row'>
    <td>";echo "<b><u>Cost: </u></b>";echo "</td>
    <td>";echo $row['cost'];echo "</td>
    <td>";echo "<b><u>Date Received: </u></b>";echo "</td>
    <td>";echo $row['date_received'];echo "</td>
</tr>";
  }
};
echo "</table>";
```

### Working jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.clicked').click(function() {
        $(this).nextUntil('.clicked').toggle();
    });
});
```

### CSS

```
.sub-row{display:none;}
```